# Looking for a job in approx 12 months... put the feelers out now?

Tags: job-search, new-job, recruitment, job-change

I started a new job around 5 months ago. The job is going quite well and I'm enjoying it for the most part, but two issues are:

1. The location means a time consuming and expensive commute (moving closer to work isn't really an option).
2. The pay isn't great (although I suppose I can ask for a pay rise once I've been there long enough).

I'm thinking of sticking with it for another year or so before looking for a job closer to home.

Previously I was freelancing and picked up a few contacts that way. A couple of which I like the idea of working at full-time.

I'm tempted to get in touch with them now just to let them know that I'll probably be looking for a job closer to home in about a year or so. I thought it would be good just to put it out there in case they have any opportunities coming up around that time.

Might this be a good idea? Or should I just keep everything under wraps until I actually plan to leave my current job?

Note that I don't plan to just contact a bunch of companies I've never spoke to previously — only those who I already have a bit of a rapport with already.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving - when should I start looking for a new job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6529/moving-when-should-i-start-looking-for-a-new-job)

Comment: What makes you want to stay for another year? If you had an offer today, would you not want to move?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I thought I'd be okay with the commute but it's proving more hassle than I expected... also the pay isn't *that* low but it's the same as my previous job and I feel like I should be earning a bit more by now. Aswell as that, the pandemic made me wanna get a job as soon as I could... but having said all that, these issues aren't enough to make me wanna leave my current job urgently or anything

Comment: @gnat I get these kind of comments on pretty much anything I ever post on this site... I'd rather stick with answers to my specific situation rather than someone else's' to be honest, let alone a post from nearly 10 years ago. But thanks all the same

Comment: @Helena partly because I feel I can pick up some good experience at this particular job that could be hard to find in other companies... and also because I left one of my other previous jobs after less than a year, so wouldn't want this kind of thing to look like too much of a habit when people look at my CV — having said that, I could be tempted to leave now should the perfect role come up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on where you are in your career.

Years ago, the prevailing wisdom was to try to keep your first job for at least two to three years so that you didn't look like a job-hopper.

Currently, some job-hopping early in a career is considered acceptable and even expected - entry-level jobs can be hit-or-miss, and it's easy to take the wrong job when one is still figuring out their best skill sets and work style.

If you do have a long history (a decade or more) of job-hopping, then it might become more important to get listings on your resume that are a year or longer. But if you do have some two-or-three year listings already, you're allowed a few hops, especially in these strange pandemic-y times.

But if you know now that the current situation is untenable - the office isn't going to move any closer and the pay cannot be negotiated, you may as well start looking now. If looking for you means networking, it may well take twelve months or longer for you to find something that will work, get interviewed (this can sometimes take three months), get an offer, pass a background check (2 weeks in itself, usually), get the references, and then wait for a new-start orientation (I know someone who had the offer and background check signed and done, but still had to wait another 5 weeks to start).

With this in mind, I wouldn't tell potential employers that you want to stay at your job for a year. Because it can take so long to track down, win and start new work, putting things in terms 'someday off in the future' makes you sound more loyal to your current job than excited about the opportunity or the company. From the hiring manager's perspective, you're either interested or you're not. It's not their job to think of you 12 months from now, and there's a good chance that they may not even been in that position in the future, effectively closing any window you may have had with that contact.

Answer (score 3):

> Might this be a good idea? or should I just keep everything under
> wraps until I actually plan to leave my current job?

To me, there are two problems with this approach.

First, it seems unlikely that a contact would know of a job opening occurring 12 months in the future. Most companies create an opening and attempt to fill it as quickly as possible.

Second, this comes across to me as "Hey, friend. I only started here 5 months ago, but already I'm planning to leave." If I were the contact, I'd have to think to myself why you wouldn't do the same in my company if I referred you.

I think you would be much better off waiting until you are actually ready to interview and accept a job offer.

Keep networking and keep your contacts fresh. But for now, keep the "in 12 months" thought to yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your response, maybe I will leave it for a while but — I don't expect them to know now if a vacancy will come up in 12 months time, I mean more along the lines of them getting in touch with me should a job become available. Also, if the reason for me leaving is due to the long commute, I shouldn't think potential employers would be put off hiring me if their location is closer to where I live